# Best advice to rename 100 + column names?

Tags: r

I have imported data but with really unattractive column names (obtained from the database I downloaded from). I was just wondering if any of you had any suggestions as to the best way to rename a dataframe with many column names in a clean way?

I am hoping to avoid `colnames(df) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3, ... "x100")` etc. This could always lead to me missing a column, or a number of errors. Do you suggest I create a data.frame first so that I know the column numbers align? i.e. row 86 of `df.col.names` actually corresponds to column 86 of `df`.

At the moment I am just talking about 1 data.frame but I have about 6/7 and they have ranges from 80 - 130 columns in each. All very ugly such as `Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...2`

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Last few column names

```
64                Long.term.debt.EUR.Last.avail..yr
65                      Long.term.debt.EUR.Year...1
66                      Long.term.debt.EUR.Year...2
67                      Long.term.debt.EUR.Year...3
68 Other.non.current.liabilities.EUR.Last.avail..yr
69       Other.non.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...1
70       Other.non.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...2
71       Other.non.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...3
72                    Provisions.EUR.Last.avail..yr
73                          Provisions.EUR.Year...1
74                          Provisions.EUR.Year...2
75                          Provisions.EUR.Year...3
76           Current.liabilities.EUR.Last.avail..yr
77                 Current.liabilities.EUR.Year...1
78                 Current.liabilities.EUR.Year...2
79                 Current.liabilities.EUR.Year...3
80                         Loans.EUR.Last.avail..yr
81                               Loans.EUR.Year...1
82                               Loans.EUR.Year...2
83                               Loans.EUR.Year...3
84                     Creditors.EUR.Last.avail..yr
85                           Creditors.EUR.Year...1
86                           Creditors.EUR.Year...2
87                           Creditors.EUR.Year...3
88     Other.current.liabilities.EUR.Last.avail..yr
89           Other.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...1
90           Other.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...2
91           Other.current.liabilities.EUR.Year...3
92   Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Last.avail..yr
93         Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...1
94         Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...2
95         Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...3
```

Comment: `names(df) = paste0("x", 1:ncol(df))`

Comment: Though I'm not sure that a meaningless column name like `x87` is better than the example name you give, which while annoyingly long, at least conveys some information about what is in the column.

Comment: The best option is probably to create a lookup table of possible bad column names and the desired column names. You could then use `match` to make sure that the appropriate new name is assigned consistently among all your data frames.

Comment: All the column names are like the example name I gave (the x1, x2, ...) was just to illustrate I dont want to type out 100 times a more usefriendly name over many dataframes :(

Comment: I am just trying to avoid the error of miss aligning the df names for instance `Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...2` with `Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...3`and then a lot of my analysis will be out

Comment: Maybe `abbreviate` can be an option. For example: `x = "Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...2"; abbreviate(gsub("\\.", "", x), minlength = 5)`

Comment: I still can't tell from your description if you need consistent column names between the 6/7 data frames or not. Is that the problem? *"I am just talking about 1 data.frame"* sounds like you just need to do this one at a time. But if you need it to be consistent between all the data frames then it makes a lot more sense to do it all at once.

Comment: The other option would be to tidy your data to a long data format. It looks like a lot of info is encoded in the column name, maybe it would be better to have a `Year` column with values 1, 2, 3, .., a `Currency` (or Region?) column with values `EUR`, a Type column with values Liability or Asset, etc., and finally a Value column with whatever the actual data value is.

Comment: The data frames have different columns, so I would have to have different columnnames between the data frames (i.e. I would have to write out again another 100 column names) - I guess I should just leave it as it is.

Comment: What is your goal? What would you want `Total.shareh..funds...liab..EUR.Year...2` to be named?

Comment: I was hoping for shorter names but when I see the names writen the way I put them in the original question they are at least intuitive, so I guess I will stick with the way they are. I thought I would just ask to see if I have missed something which could keep the intuition in the name but would require less typing when making analysis/printing tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a file you don't have to use the first row as the headers. You can skip the first row and assign default column names (V1, V2, etc).

```
d <- read.csv(file = "foo.csv",skip = 1,header = F)
```